# Update data in background

Tags: android, performance, service, android-asynctask

In my application I need to have a periodically updated contact-list, group-list and folder list updated from server. I am saving them to the save preferences right now. Currently I've implemented a method that if I have lists of each type I need, I skip the update on login and call a background asyncTask that update this data after the login. The problem is that is the connection is low the user can login but then they can't do nothing, waiting the background updating that block the others http requests.
How can I refresh this data periodically? like a service that update data even if the app isn't active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use a `Service`.

[Android Service Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

**manifest.xml**

```
<service
    android:name="MyService"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/service_name">
</service>
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //TODO do something useful
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
   //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
   return null;
}
}
```

**Start a Service**

```
// use this to start and trigger a service
Intent i= new Intent(context, MyService.class);
// potentially add data to the intent
i.putExtra("KEY1", "Value to be used by the service");
context.startService(i);
```

Comment: It can be runned periodically in device background without the request from the app?

Comment: Yes, Service runs in background